# Unable to build new package for angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am unable to create a new package for angular. Below are details of software versions

- npm -v 
  v6.1.0
- node -v
  v8.11.3
- ng -v
  v6.0.8

Im getting the below error while creating the project with **ng new project_name**

[image: Im getting this error while creating the project with **ng new project_name**]

This error comes when I try to create new project in my office while my same laptop works fine when I try to create it at home. It seems that some of the ACL's are blocking to create the new package.

Can anyone guide me that which URL/IP does angular uses to create a new project so I can allow the package on the office network. Or any way around for this issue will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for providing your support. I have been working on the issue lately and the problem seems to be solved now. The issue seemed to be with node v8.11.3 and after updating it to the latest version it is working fine now.

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

So my updated node version is now v10.5.0